# Set Multimedia Annotation Rendition Options with iText

Tags: java, annotations, itext, multimedia

So I'm using PdfAnnotation.createScreen() to create a Multimedia Annotation that plays an mp3 file when clicked. It's all working very well, EXCEPT I now want to set the Rendition Options to hide the playback window, and can't find out how to do it.

In Acrobat it's done via Properties - Settings - Renditions - Edit - Playback Location - Hidden.

I believe this corresponds to the C key under table 280 (section 13.2.5 Media Play Parameters) of the PDF 1.7 specs (page 496 of the PDF reference file), but I'm not sure how to set it using iText for Java... Any help is much appreciated.